# onclick event only called once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two sprites, a player and a boss in a game.
When I click on a html button "attack one", "attack two" etc. I change the sprite of the boss for an attacked one (animation where the boss changes), I add a div to the html which are a bubble (bullet in my game) and I create an animation on this div so the bubble moves toward the boss.

Once the bubble touches the boss, I delete the div associated with the bubble and I set back the boss sprite to the standing one (when the boss is not attacked).

My code works well, but only one time. If I reclick on the button without reloading the page, it doesn't work.

So, why does it only work once?

Thanks!

```js
    function attack_one() {
        document.getElementById("attack_one").onclick = () => {
            boss = new TiledImage("sprites/attackedBoss.png", 8, 2, 200, true, 1, "boss");
            boss.changeMinMaxInterval(1,8);
            document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="bubble"></div>';
            let x = 330;
            if(x < 500) {
                tick();
            }
            function tick() {
                if(x < 500) {
                    document.getElementById("bubble").style.left = x + "px";
                    x+= 4;
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("bubble").outerHTML = "";
                    setTimeout( () => {
                        boss = new TiledImage("sprites/standingBoss.png", 8, 2, 200, true, 1, "boss");
                        boss.changeMinMaxInterval(1,8);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the JS only. After the boss gets attacked, do you recreate the #attack_one element? An click event will only work with elements that exist when the JS is loaded. If you delete the original element and recreate it, your code will no longer work. You may want to look into event delegation instead: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="bubble"></div>'` is not a good way to add an element to the page, it serialises the entire content and replaces it with the new bit added, removing any listeners that may have been added dynamically. `document.getElementById("bubble").outerHTML = ""` is not a good way to delete an element.

Comment: Oh, I see, I replace my button with the onclick element and then it wont work... Thanks a lot! I'll use dom instead of innerhtml.